# What are pros and cons, between connecting UICollectionView to DataSource, Delegate using Xcode drag-n-drop, and connecting programatically

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

Most of the tutorial video I went through, are teaching us to connect `UICollectionView` with data source/ delegate using Xcode drag-n-drop.

However, I also notice that, it is possible to connect data source/ delegate without using Xcode drag-n-drop - https://riptutorial.com/ios/example/5762/create-a-collection-view-programmatically

I was wondering, what are some pros and cons for these 2 different mythology? Which is the more recommended way?

Comment: There is no difference in both. 
In example page you shared, they have allocated a collection view programmatically and you have added delegate and datasource programatically. In case you drag and drop collection view in storyboard, you can add from there or add programatically too.

Comment: There is no real difference, but by putting it in code you see that your delegate is set, you most likely will look int the code more often than to storyboard.

Comment: Completely no difference. But if you work with team and work on same storyboard, merging storyboard could be very annoying.